# Are there other oracle services beside Oraclize that provides a user-friendly API and allows for competition?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, oracles

> Are there other oracle services beside Oraclize that that provides a user-friendly API and allows for competition?

I want to implement the scheme where my contract request the same ressource, e.g., weather data, from several oracles and then chooses either the most frequent result or the average of the results (where possible).

I know of the authenticity proofs supplied by Oraclize, but in this case I want to test the scheme outlined above.

The only oracle service I know of is Oraclize. Are their other equivalent oracle services in terms of user-friendly API etc.? If not, how do I roll out my own oracle service?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.realitykeys.com/. I think Edmund works for them - he'll probably be around to comment further.

Answer (score 3):

The following is an attempt at an exhaustive list of potential Oraclize alternatives or complements. A listing is not an endorsement, and I do not make any claims towards their current practicality or usability. For full disclosure, I am currently contracted by Oraclize, and will do my best to mention Oracle type services I'm aware of, that may be usable with Ethereum in some way:

- Town Crier
- RealityKeys
- Chainlink
- Gnosis
- Augur
- BlockOne IQ
- Streamr
- BTC Relay
- TinyOracle (github repo for running your own Oracle)
- TrueBit

I can make amendments if you leave a comment and I missed a service.

Answer (score 0):

From the Oraclize [documentation](https://docs.oraclize.it/#data-sources):

> The URL data source type enables access to any API or web page on the Internet. It supports both HTTP GET and HTTP POST request. If only one parameters is specified in the query, the service will default to perform an HTTP GET request. If a second parameter is specified, then the service will perform an HTTP POST request, posting the second parameter as data. Note that if the second parameter is valid JSON, then it will be posted as such. The URL data source type supports TLSNotary Proofs and Android Proofs. More advanced HTTP capabilities, such as Basic Authentication or OAuth, can be build by leveraging the computation data source type.

Using the URL data source type, you can create a data source for your contracts with just a basic API that's accessed on a web server. Oraclize functions as the Oracle (interface between your API and the contract) so you don't need to worry about any of the complexity associated with implementing your own Oracle.

Comment: Don't I need to implement my own blockchain monitor to implement my own oracle?

Comment: It's important to understand the distinction between an oracle and a data source. When the oracle is queried by a contract on the blockchain it creates an API request to the data source, basically functioning as a middle man between the contract and the data source. What Oraclize allows you to do is use its oracle to access **your** data source. [Here's](https://goo.gl/XPdTZw) an example of a contract that uses the Oraclize gateway to access the Kraken API. Would it be helpful if I edited my original answer to include the example and go into more detail?

Comment: But I need to trust Oraclize. My intention was to use multiple oracles "middle men". Thereby, if one oracle is corrupt, I will use the value (data) returned by the majority of the oracles. This is not equivalent to use the same oracle with multiple data sources, is it?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was deleted. So, I will try one more time :)

I hope that this information is still relevant. Try chainthis.com

The question was: "The only oracle service I know of is Oraclize. Are their other equivalent oracle services in terms of user-friendly API etc.? If not, how do I roll out my own oracle service?" And I talk about another one service besides oraclize. Chainthis is a service that allows creating blockchain oracles. Also, they have an API for it chainthis.com/for-developers